# Simple Class or array of Linkedlist

Tags: java

I have a decision to make. I want to write a list of names and directions. Its very small list and i dont want to access it outside of the class.

I have 2 options to store the elements dynamically:
1. A nested linkedlist
2. An small class whith two members, and add this element to a single Linkedlist.

Which one is the right approach?

Thanks a lot,
David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an inner class - the code will be easier to read.

```
List<List<String>> list = ..;
String name = list.get(0).get(0);
```

is less readable than:

```
List<Location> list = ..;
String name = list.get(0).getName();
```

Another option is to use a `Map<String, String>` where the key is the name, and the value - the location. That's in case your normal usage involves looking up a location based on name. If both operations are regular, you can check `BiMap` from guava libraries.

Comment: is HashMap not preffered by having name related with directions.

Comment: @Suresh S - if you are going to look them up by name - yes. If they are just pairs - it can be list. I'll add an update about that case.